# SVN ! files...delete?

Tags: svn

I have some files in SVN marked

! filename

That I would just like to delete (remove) from SVN...it's kind of a mistake but they are files I deleted from the folder that I should have just typed:

svn delete my-filename

Is there any way to just get rid of these in SVN??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could 'svn update' and then delete them properly using 'svn delete'.

Comment: Hm I just tried that and it's saying my file (that I am trying to "delete") doesn't exist?

Comment: Wait, I just tried svn remove instead of delete and now it works...go figure (aren't they the same command??)